# maven build for sonar failed while installing jdbc driver

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I am trying to run `mvn sonar:sonar` on my parent Maven project.

Environment:

- Mac OSX Yosemite
- Maven version 3.2.1
- Sonar version - tried both with 5.1 and 5.1.1
- Database - tried both with MySQL and Sonar built in h2.

I am getting below error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project Fail to execute request [code=400, url=http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.txt]: Fail to download [http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.txt]. Response code: 400 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project payback: Fail to execute request [code=400, url=http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.txt]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to execute request [code=400, url=http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.txt]
```

**EDIT**

Looks like the the issue is not directly related to sonar. I changed the settings in  .m2/settings.xml to point to the remote sonar server. It still gave the same error message.
Here is the listing of settings.xml

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.host.url>http://192.168.1.111:9000</sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Looks like something to do with sonar-maven-plugin.

Comment: You should check server logs.

Comment: Checked. Nothing specific in the logs.

Comment: You can't expect correct support without more information about your environment. Please provide the server logs and the version of SQ. Moreover does http://localhost:9000 show the homepage ? Thanks

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource Thanks for the response. updated the question with the environment details. 
Here is the same
Environment: 
Mac OSX Yosmite, 
Maven version 3.2.1, 
sonar version - tried both with 5.1 and 5.1.1
Database - tried both with Mysql and sonar built in h2.

Yes localhost:9000 shows the homepage.